# Not Understanding Git Ignore

Tags: git

I am attempting to add all `.env` files to be ignored, so I am running the following commands:

```bash
cd .git/
vim .gitignore
(start editing the file by hitting the i key)
(add the following to the first line: *.env)
(save the edits by hitting the escape key, typing wq, and pressing enter)
cd ../
git status
git rm -r --cached config.env
git status
```

When I call `git rm -r --cached config.env` I get the following message:

> fatal: pathspec 'config.env' did not match any files

Even though the file appear in the list from the `git status` executed just before.

The second `git status` still shows my env in the untracked files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.gitignore` goes in the root directory of your repository (or any other directory under which you want it to take effect), not in the `.git` directory.

Example:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    config.env

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ echo '*.env' > .gitignore
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .gitignore

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood where the file went but it makes sense that it would go in the root directory.